What is the abnormal peak in XRD pattern of anatase TiO2
A successfully synthesized titanium dioxide powder was analyzed with X-ray diffraction. The powder was synthesized by my teacher and no information about the synthesizing method. The XRD plot is shown below

It is indeed the anatase phase of TiO2, my attention was caught by the appearance of a moderately strong peak at 22.5o which is not observed in any of the reference, inclusive of rutile, anatase and brookite.

Any idea with the abnormal peak?

Is it on a substrate? What were the precursors?

Unfortunately, there is no information about that. I guess I will just ask for experience from other experts.
